# G-suite Forms Quiz. Random answers

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, random, google-workspace, google-form-quiz

I'm looking at a script to make forms from a spreadsheet, I found some application that already does, but I wanted to make some modification.

https://scooltic.es/generador-de-examenes-aleatorios-con-google-forms/

I wish I could get multiple answers out randomly.

I have found that with:

- `setIsQuiz(true)` converts a form into a questionnaire.
- `setShuffleQuestions(true)` questions in a form are randomized.
- `setRequired(true)` is obligated to answer the question.

But I don't see how to make the answers of `MultipleChoiceItem` random, for example.

I think it should be here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item

But I can't find the solution, does anyone know?